# compare room database valuw with user input

Tags: kotlin, android-room

How can I compare the value from the room database with the text field? I want to compare the user input value with the credential view model but I have no idea how to do it. I have already set the query in the credentialDao so the value fetched should be inside the view model. But I just could not compare it.
CredentialDao

```
@Dao
interface CredentialDao {
    //if user name same ignore
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun addUser(credential: Credential)

    @Update
    suspend fun updateUser(credential: Credential)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM credential_table WHERE userName LIKE :userName AND password LIKE :password")
    fun readAllData(userName: String, password: String): Credential
}
```

CredentialDatabase

```
@Database(entities = [Credential::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(dateConverter::class)
abstract class CredentialDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun credentialDao(): CredentialDao

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: CredentialDatabase? = null
        val migration_1_2: Migration = object: Migration(2,1){
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase){

            }
        }

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): CredentialDatabase{
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if(tempInstance != null){
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this){
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    CredentialDatabase::class.java,
                    "credential_database"
                ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Credential Repository

```
class CredentialRepository(private val credentialDao: CredentialDao) {


    suspend fun addCredential(credential: Credential){
        credentialDao.addUser(credential)
    }
    suspend fun updateCredential(credential: Credential){
        credentialDao.updateUser(credential)
    }
    fun readAllData(username: String,password:String) {
        credentialDao.readAllData(username,password)
    }
}
```

CredentialViewModel

```
class CredentialViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository: CredentialRepository

    init{
        val credentialDao = CredentialDatabase.getDatabase(application).credentialDao()
        repository = CredentialRepository(credentialDao)
    }
    fun addCredential(credential: Credential){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            repository.addCredential(credential)
        }
    }
    fun updateCredential(credential: Credential){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            repository.updateCredential(credential)
        }
    }
    fun readAllData(userName: String, password: String){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            repository.readAllData(userName, password)
        }
    }

}
```

LoginActivity

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mUserViewModel: CredentialViewModel
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        mUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CredentialViewModel::class.java)
        val login = findViewById<Button>(R.id.login_btn)
        login?.setOnClickListener {
            val userName = username_txt.text.toString().trim();
            val password = password_txt.text.toString().trim();
            if(userName.isEmpty()||password.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(
                    applicationContext,
                    "Please fill out all field!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }else{
                mUserViewModel.readAllData(userName, password)
                if(user!=null){
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Successfully Login!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("Username",userName)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Wrong Password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `readAllData()` method in your `CredentialRepository` is incorrect, because this function needs to return the query result to `CredentialViewModel`. Your correct approach is to pass the query result to `ViewModel`.

When trying to log in, you should also call the method defined in `ViewModel` and pass `username` and `password` to this method for retrieval. The final result defines a `LiveData<Boolean>` to represent whether you log in successfully.

```kotlin
class CredentialViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val mResult = MutableLiveData<Credential>()

    val resultLiveData: LiveData<Credential> get() = mResult

    private val repository: CredentialRepository

    init{
        val credentialDao = CredentialDatabase.getDatabase(application).credentialDao()
        repository = CredentialRepository(credentialDao)
    }
    fun addCredential(credential: Credential){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            repository.addCredential(credential)
        }
    }
    fun updateCredential(credential: Credential){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            repository.updateCredential(credential)
        }
    }
    fun readAllData(userName: String, password: String){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            mResult.postValue(repository.readAllData(userName, password))
        }
    }

}
```

```kotlin
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mUserViewModel: CredentialViewModel
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        mUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CredentialViewModel::class.java)
        val login = findViewById<Button>(R.id.login_btn)
        mUserViewModel.resultLiveData.observe(this@LoginActivity, { credential ->
            if(credential!=null){
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Successfully Login!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("Username",userName)
                startActivity(intent)
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Wrong Password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })

        login?.setOnClickListener {
            val userName = username_txt.text.toString().trim();
            val password = password_txt.text.toString().trim();
            if (userName.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    applicationContext,
                    "Please fill out all field!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            } else {
                mUserViewModel.readAllData(userName, password)
            }

        }
    }


}
```

modify Repository

```kotlin
class CredentialRepository(private val credentialDao: CredentialDao) {


    suspend fun addCredential(credential: Credential){
        credentialDao.addUser(credential)
    }
    suspend fun updateCredential(credential: Credential){
        credentialDao.updateUser(credential)
    }
    fun readAllData(username: String,password:String) :Credential{
        return credentialDao.readAllData(username,password)
    }
}
```

Comment: @dfw can u give me a guide on how to write the query?

Comment: does it affect the result?

Comment: select all is just select id, username and password but just that I did not use the id

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake just now. In fact, you only need LiveData to solve this problem. I'm really sorry, if I have time, I will update my code tomorrow.

Comment: thanks alot for helping. I am quite new in this and I really tried for like the whole day but everyone seems to use different method when doing login function

Comment: I edited the code very quickly, I hope to help you :)

Comment: there is an error with the mResult.postValue(repository.readAllData(userName, password)). Type mismatch.
Required:
MutableList<Credential>!
Found:
Unit

Comment: year~ it 's make a mistake. i mofidy

Comment: I still can't figure out the error and also the viewlifecycleowner also have error

Comment: Since I wrote it temporarily before get off work, there was no build. Currently I have re-edited the code.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: there is still an error at read all data function in view model. Type mismatch.
Required:
Credential!
Found:
Unit

Comment: I forgot to modify the code related to the repo, which caused the query result to not be returned.

Comment: thanks a lot. Appreciate for your help. It works fine now